# Cannot download GraphQL schema from endpoint

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, graphql, prisma

I'm currently using [graphql-cli from Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs/1.10/graphql-ecosystem/graphql-cli/overview-quaidah9pj) to download the schema from endpoint.  But, even after I deploy the changes I made to my schema, which gets deployed successfully, whenever I try to download the schema, I get `project prisma - No changes`.  And the generated `prisma.graphql` is left unchanged.

I use the following command to download the schema:

```js
graphql get-schema -p prisma --dotenv config/dev.env
```

`dev.env` is simply to get `PRISMA_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:4466/` environment variable.

I tried to generate `prisma.graphql` in a different way by having the following in `prisma.yml`:

```
endpoint: ${env:PRISMA_ENDPOINT}
datamodel: datamodel.prisma
generate:
   - generator: graphql-schema
     output: ./generated/
```

And executed `prisma generate`, but I get the error:

> ▸    [WARNING] in
>   /Users/F/Documents/d/server/prisma/prisma.yml: A valid
>   environment  ▸    variable to satisfy the declaration
>   'env:PRISMA_ENDPOINT' could not be found.

Tried stopping and recreating Docker as well as deleting the `node_module` and re-installing, but to no avail.

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "graphql-basics",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "babel src --out-dir dist --copy-files",
    "dev": "env-cmd ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js --ext js,graphql --exec babel-node",
    "test": "env-cmd ./config/test.env jest --watch --runInBand",
    "get-schema": "graphql get-schema -p prisma --dotenv config/dev.env"
  },
  "jest": {
    "globalSetup": "./tests/jest/globalSetup.js",
    "globalTeardown": "./tests/jest/globalTeardown.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cross-fetch": "^2.2.2",
    "env-cmd": "^8.0.2",
    "google-auth-library": "^4.2.3",
    "graphql-cli": "^3.0.14",    
    "graphql-yoga": "^1.14.10",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "prisma-binding": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.23.0",
    "jest": "^23.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "graphql": "^14.5.8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error "variable to satisfy the declaration 'env:PRISMA_ENDPOINT' could not be found." when calling `prisma generate` you should either set the `PRISMA_ENDPOINT` variable manually or load it via `dotenv`. For example you could run `npx dotenv -- prisma generate` to load the env vars from your .env file.

To download the schema from the endpoint via `graphql get-schema` make sure to provide a properly configured `.graphqlconfig.yml` and provide the correct project. 
A sample configuration for a prisma project could look like this:

```
projects:
  prisma:
    schemaPath: 'src/schema.graphql'
    extensions:
      endpoints:
        default: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql'
  database:
    schemaPath: 'src/generated/prisma.graphql'
    extensions:
      prisma: 'database/prisma.yml'
      endpoints:
        default: 'http://localhost:4466'
```